# How do I find the number of people with a certain role in Discord.js?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am trying to find how many people have a certain role. I have done this

```
client.on('message', (message) => {
    let guild = await message.guild.fetchMembers();
    let roleID = '3933783737379';
    let memberCount = guild.roles.get(roleID).members.size;
    message.channel.send(memberCount + " members have this role!");
});
```

But the error tells me that fetchMembers() and get() is no longer a function. May I know if the code has been deprecated, if so how do I find the number of people with a certain role? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`fetchMembers()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v11/class/Guild?scrollTo=fetchMembers) was deprecated, you have to use `message.guild.members.fetch()` now!

[Moving to v13 guide](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v13.html)

Also your code can be optimized, just use:

```js
let roleID = '3933783737379';
let role = message.guild.roles.cache.get(roleID);
message.channel.send({content: `${role.members.size} members have this role!`});
```